# How to Know the time duration a token was streaming it's video to a session in opentok

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, videochat, opentok

I connected , subscribed to a session in opentok with a token and streamed my video.

Now How do I get informations like How much time did my video streamed, and many other informations which can be useful for data analysis.

```
 var apiKey = "*****";
 var sessionId = "**************************";
 var token = "************";


            var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey);

            var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

            session.connect(apiKey, token);
            session.addEventListener("sessionConnected",
                           sessionConnectedHandler);

            session.addEventListener("streamCreated",
                           streamCreatedHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of these data yourself. For example, after creating a publisher you can  send a post request to your server with the current timestamp `Date.now()`

When the user disconnects, you will get a sessionDisconnected event from someone else in the session, you can send an event to your server with the current timestamp `Date.now()` to mark the end time.

To identify the streams that have been disconnected, simply make sure you are sending the user's connectionId in your requests: `session.connection.connectionId` and `stream.connection.connectionId`

Alternatively, you can try out OpenTok's [raptor SDK](http://labs.tokbox.com/raptor/), which is simply a Java SDK that you can use in your Java backend to get a request every time a user connects/disconnects to a session and other events. Unfortunately this only works with Java for now, OpenTok will work to support more SDKs soon.