# How to Know the duration of time a token or connection was streaming it's video to a session in opentok

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webrtc, videochat, opentok

I published to a session in opentok with a token and streamed my video.

Now how can I get information like how much time did my video streamed, and many other information which can be useful for data analysis?

```
var apiKey = "*****";
var sessionId = "**************************";
var token = "************";

var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey);
var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

session.connect(apiKey, token);
session.addEventListener("sessionConnected", sessionConnectedHandler);
session.addEventListener("streamCreated", streamCreatedHandler);
```

Comment: Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573441/how-to-know-the-time-duration-a-token-was-streaming-its-video-to-a-session-in-o), it's asking the same question

Answer (score 0):

in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573441/how-to-know-the-time-duration-a-token-was-streaming-its-video-to-a-session-in-o):

You have to keep track of these data yourself. For example, after creating a publisher you can send a post request to your server with the current timestamp Date.now()

When the user disconnects, you will get a sessionDisconnected event from someone else in the session, you can send an event to your server with the current timestamp Date.now() to mark the end time.

To identify the streams that have been disconnected, simply make sure you are sending the user's connectionId in your requests: session.connection.connectionId and stream.connection.connectionId

Alternatively, you can try out [OpenTok raptor SDK](http://labs.tokbox.com/raptor/), which is simply a Java SDK that you can use in your Java backend to get a request every time a user connects/disconnects to a session and other events. Unfortunately this only works with Java for now, OpenTok will work to support more SDKs soon.